# plt.show() prints only the graph and no other print() function in stdout

Tags: python, matplotlib, printing

I am running the following python script:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

list_1=[(0.0002727508544921875, 30.272794723510742), (0.0006632804870605469, 30.036267280578613)]
print("hello world!")
def visualize_runtimes(results, title):
    start, stop = np.array(results).T
    print("start: ", start)
    print("stop:", stop)
    plt.barh(range(len(start)),stop-start,left=start)
    plt.grid(axis='x')
    plt.ylabel("Tasks")
    plt.xlabel("Seconds")
    plt.title(title)
    plt.show()
    return stop[-1]-start[0]

visualize_runtimes(list_1, "Mutli")
```

However, only the plot is printed with any additional print() function to be omitted. What is the reason of this happening?

**My output**

[image]

**My desired output** to present in the stdout all the print() functions + plt.show(), either the print is inside or outside of the function.

```
"hello world"
"start: [0.00027275 0.00066328]"
"stop: [30.27279472 30.03626728]"
plot
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your exact goal is, but maybe you want to put your "Hello world statement" inside the function if that's what you are looking for?

Comment: No I want to print everything inside and out of my function.. As you can see I have 3 print functions and a plt.show()....in the stdout only the plot is presented, while the three print functions are not. I want all the prints to be illustrated

Comment: When I run your code I get the plot presented and start and stop printed to stdout. Or do you want your print(start) as some kind of label in your plot?

Comment: For a reason when I run the same function I don't get the prints of start, stop in sttdout.

Comment: It does look like you run it in some kind of IDE. Maybe that's the reason? If you are. Try running it in a terminal.

Comment: Ok I will try that

Comment: Yeah you are right, running this on my local Jupyter Notebook prints everything....But when I run this from a Databricks cluster cell block prints only the plot and not any other print function

Comment: I will try to fix this on my own because it's probably an issue when calling the visualization function...

Comment: I have same issue with databricks. Is it possible to use print statements and graph in the same cell in databricks notebook? @NikSp

Comment: @Lufy I haven't resolved this yet. Actually, it didn't bother me because I was experimenting at that time and thought it was a bug. If it's not fixed by now I guess is something that Databricks should be concerned about. The multiple print statements and plot work perfectly together in Jupyter. Thus, it's weird that the same logic does not work for Databricks IDE since those two IDEs are quite similar.

Comment: Thanks @NikSp for your reply. I'll probably ignore it for now.